# Coco annotations: convert RLE to polygon segmentation

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, annotations, image-segmentation

I have coco style annotations (json format) with Both segmentations And bboxes.
Most of the segmentations are given as list-of-lists of the pixels (polygon).

The problem is that some segmentations are given as a dictionary (with 'counts' and 'size' keys) that represent RLE values, and in these cases the 'iscrowd' key is equal to 1 (normally it is equal to 0).

I would like to convert all the 'annotations' with iscrowd==1 to be represented as polygons instead of RLE.

I do not need the mask [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74957352/19155645), but just the json file to have only polygon shaped segmentations.

Here is an example of a few annotations (from the same image), note how in the first two the segmentation is in polygon shape, and the latter two it is in RLE shape:

```
{'id': 53, 'image_id': 4, 'category_id': 2037037930, 'segmentation': [[344.51, 328.83, 316.02, 399.73, 358.3, 399.78, 375.85, 336.07]], 'area': 2561.4049499999965, 'bbox': [316.02, 328.83, 59.83000000000004, 70.94999999999999], 'iscrowd': 0, 'extra': {}} 

{'id': 54, 'image_id': 4, 'category_id': 2037037930, 'segmentation': [[376.43, 233.52, 368.93, 250.71, 375.96, 252.89, 369.4, 269.76, 378.62, 273.83, 372.21, 292.42, 400.09, 302.34, 400.09, 302.11, 400.1, 242.04]], 'area': 1596.5407000000123, 'bbox': [368.93, 233.52, 31.170000000000016, 68.81999999999996], 'iscrowd': 0, 'extra': {}} 

{'id': 67, 'image_id': 4, 'category_id': 2037037930, 'segmentation': {'counts': [55026, 2, 396, 4, 394, 7, 391, 9, 389, 12, 386, 14, 384, 17, 381, 19, 379, 21, 377, 24, 374, 26, 372, 29, 369, 31, 367, 33, 365, 36, 362, 38, 360, 41, 357, 43, 355, 46, 352, 48, 350, 50, 348, 53, 345, 55, 343, 58, 340, 38, 1, 21, 338, 37, 5, 21, 335, 37, 7, 21, 335, 34, 10, 19, 338, 32, 12, 16, 340, 33, 11, 14, 342, 33, 11, 11, 346, 33, 11, 8, 348, 33, 10, 7, 350, 33, 8, 8, 351, 34, 5, 11, 351, 33, 3, 13, 351, 49, 351, 49, 352, 49, 351, 49, 351, 49, 352, 48, 352, 49, 351, 49, 352, 46, 354, 44, 356, 41, 359, 39, 362, 36, 364, 35, 365, 35, 366, 35, 365, 35, 365, 35, 366, 34, 366, 34, 366, 35, 366, 34, 366, 34, 366, 32, 368, 29, 372, 25, 375, 23, 377, 20, 381, 18, 382, 19, 381, 19, 382, 18, 382, 18, 382, 19, 382, 18, 382, 18, 382, 19, 381, 19, 382, 16, 384, 13, 387, 9, 392, 5, 395, 2, 73808], 'size': [400, 400]}, 'area': 2598.0, 'bbox': [137, 174, 79, 65], 'iscrowd': 1, 'extra': {}} 

{'id': 68, 'image_id': 4, 'category_id': 2037037930, 'segmentation': {'counts': [76703, 2, 396, 4, 394, 7, 391, 9, 389, 11, 387, 14, 384, 16, 382, 19, 379, 21, 377, 23, 375, 26, 372, 28, 370, 30, 368, 33, 365, 35, 364, 37, 363, 37, 364, 36, 364, 37, 364, 36, 364, 36, 364, 37, 364, 36, 364, 37, 363, 37, 364, 36, 364, 37, 364, 36, 364, 36, 364, 37, 364, 15, 1, 20, 364, 13, 4, 19, 365, 10, 6, 20, 363, 9, 8, 20, 361, 9, 11, 20, 358, 9, 13, 20, 356, 11, 14, 19, 354, 14, 13, 20, 351, 16, 13, 20, 348, 20, 13, 19, 346, 22, 13, 20, 343, 24, 13, 20, 341, 27, 13, 20, 338, 29, 13, 20, 336, 32, 13, 19, 334, 34, 13, 20, 331, 37, 12, 20, 331, 37, 13, 19, 332, 36, 12, 21, 331, 37, 8, 24, 332, 36, 5, 28, 331, 37, 1, 31, 331, 69, 332, 69, 331, 69, 332, 68, 332, 69, 331, 69, 332, 68, 332, 69, 332, 68, 332, 69, 331, 69, 332, 68, 332, 48, 1, 20, 331, 45, 5, 19, 332, 41, 8, 19, 332, 38, 12, 19, 332, 36, 13, 19, 332, 37, 12, 20, 331, 37, 13, 19, 332, 36, 13, 19, 332, 37, 13, 19, 332, 36, 13, 19, 332, 37, 12, 19, 332, 37, 13, 19, 332, 36, 13, 19, 332, 37, 13, 19, 332, 36, 12, 20, 332, 36, 10, 22, 332, 37, 6, 26, 332, 36, 4, 28, 332, 37, 1, 28, 335, 63, 337, 61, 339, 59, 342, 56, 344, 53, 348, 50, 350, 48, 352, 46, 355, 43, 357, 40, 360, 38, 363, 35, 365, 33, 368, 30, 370, 28, 372, 25, 376, 22, 378, 20, 381, 17, 383, 15, 385, 12, 389, 9, 391, 7, 394, 4, 396, 2, 40521], 'size': [400, 400]}, 'area': 4551.0, 'bbox': [191, 253, 108, 82], 'iscrowd': 1, 'extra': {}}
```

---

##### Failed test 1:

I already tried the following:

```
for annotation in coco_data['annotations']:
    if type(annotation['segmentation']) == dict:
        # Get the values of the dictionary
        height = annotation['segmentation']['size'][0]
        width = annotation['segmentation']['size'][1]
        counts = annotation['segmentation']['counts']

        # Decode the RLE encoded counts
        rle = np.array(counts).reshape(-1, 2)
        starts, lengths = rle[:, 0], rle[:, 1]
        starts -= 1
        ends = starts + lengths
        pixels = []
        for lo, hi in zip(starts, ends):
            pixels.extend(range(lo, hi))
        pixels = np.array(pixels)

        # Convert the 1D pixels array to a 2D array
        segments = np.zeros((height, width), dtype=np.uint8)
        segments[pixels // width, pixels % width] = 1
        segments = np.where(segments == 1)

        # Update the segmentation and iscrowd fields
        annotation['segmentation'] = [segments[1].tolist(), segments[0].tolist()]
        annotation['iscrowd'] = 0
```

But got the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-1bf7f4af292c> in <module>
     16 
     17         # Decode the RLE encoded counts
---> 18         rle = np.array(counts).reshape(-1, 2)
     19         starts, lengths = rle[:, 0], rle[:, 1]
     20         starts -= 1

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 183 into shape (2)
```

afaik, it expectes RLE to be an even length? not sure where is the problem and how to solve it.

---

##### Failed test 2:

then i tried something a bit different with `import pycocotools.mask as mask` and `import skimage.measure as measure` and the following function:

```
def rle_to_polygon(rle, height, width):
    if isinstance(rle, list):
        rle = mask.frPyObjects(rle, height, width)
    rle = mask.decode(rle)
    contours = measure.find_contours(rle, 0.5)
    polygon = []
    for contour in contours:
        contour = np.fliplr(contour) - 1
        contour = contour.clip(min=0)
        contour = contour.astype(int)
        if len(contour) >= 4:
            polygon.append(contour.tolist())
    return polygon
```

I receive

```
<ipython-input-43-84d17a601509> in rle_to_polygon(rle, height, width)
     79 def rle_to_polygon(rle, height, width):
     80     if isinstance(rle, list):
---> 81         rle = mask.frPyObjects(rle, height, width)
     82     rle = mask.decode(rle)
     83     contours = measure.find_contours(rle, 0.5)

pycocotools/_mask.pyx in pycocotools._mask.frPyObjects()

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

This is my code for the task:

```py
import logging
import cv2
from pycocotools import mask as cocomask
import copy

def rle_to_coco(annotation: dict) -> list[dict]:
    """Transform the rle coco annotation (a single one) into coco style.
    In this case, one mask can contain several polygons, later leading to several `Annotation` objects.
    In case of not having a valid polygon (the mask is a single pixel) it will be an empty list.
    Parameters
    ----------
    annotation : dict
        rle coco style annotation
    Returns
    -------
    list[dict]
        list of coco style annotations (in dict format)
    """

    annotation["segmentation"] = cocomask.frPyObjects(
        annotation["segmentation"],
        annotation["segmentation"]["size"][0],
        annotation["segmentation"]["size"][1],
    )

    maskedArr = cocomask.decode(annotation["segmentation"])
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(maskedArr, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    segmentation = []

    for contour in contours:
        if contour.size >= 6:
            segmentation.append(contour)

    if len(segmentation) == 0:
        logging.debug(
            f"Annotation with id {annotation['id']} is not valid, it has no segmentations."
        )
        annotations = []

    else:
        annotations = list()
        for i, seg in enumerate(segmentation):

            single_annotation = copy.deepcopy(annotation)
            single_annotation["segmentation_coords"] = (
                seg.astype(float).flatten().tolist()
            )
            single_annotation["bbox"] = list(cv2.boundingRect(seg))
            single_annotation["area"] = cv2.contourArea(seg)
            single_annotation["instance_id"] = annotation["id"]
            single_annotation["annotation_id"] = f"{annotation['id']}_{i}"

            annotations.append(single_annotation)

    return annotations
```

You need `opencv` and `pycocotools`to use this code:

- `pip install opencv-python`
- `pip install pycocotools`

Note that the input annotation is one of the items inside the coco dict `annotations` key. Something like this:

```json
{
    "image_id": 1,
    "category_id": 1,
    "bbox": [
        485.0489501953125,
        660.6587524414062,
        13.161041259765625,
        10.61248779296875
    ],
    "score": 0.8787025809288025,
    "segmentation": {
        "size": [
            960,
            1280
        ],
        "counts": "jXX>1mm03O1N10000000000001NY]mf0"
    },
    "id": 1,
    "iscrowd": 0,
    "attributes": {
        "occluded": false
    }
},
```

If a mask in rle format contains more than one mask not connected, the function will return a list with each of those masks in coco format.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks, I still have an issue though, your "counts" is a string (is it a hashed form or something similar?) how did you get to this format? my counts is a long list of integers (as in the example i showed above). 
because of that difference i get an error.
Any suggestions how to resolve?
```/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pycocotools/mask.py in decode(rleObjs)
---> 91         return _mask.decode([rleObjs])[:,:,0]
pycocotools/_mask.pyx in pycocotools._mask.decode()
pycocotools/_mask.pyx in pycocotools._mask._frString()
TypeError: Expected bytes, got list```

Comment: Are you using detectron2 or another model?

Comment: [YOLOv7-segmentation](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7/tree/u7/seg)

Comment: I have just updated my code! Can you check if its works? Note that the [x, y, x, y, ...] coords are added to the coco mask in the field `segmentation_coords` inside `segmentation` key.

Comment: thanks a lot, it compiles, but i still dont think it gives sensible result - the length of the `segmentation_coords` is 338 which is way longer than the expected length (notice in the examples I provided above, the polygons are much shorter than the 'counts' that we now converted).  Do you know maybe what is the issue here? also, i notice the values are repeating, maybe the are repetitive for whatever reason? Thanks again!

Comment: Have you tried to plot the resltus? Note that with oepncv contour extraction, the number of points may be different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251603/discussion-between-cuartero-and-arieai).