# How to measure the dimensions of a segment with Coco/Segment Anything?

Tags: python, deep-learning, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation, coco

Is there a way to take a COCO/Segement Anything - If I take and electron microscope image, how would I go about classifying the segment into a polygon that has known measurable features. I want to measure the segment.

I like how Microscopy Image Browser incorporates segment anything.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3pivV4udGU

But I think it is missing the classify into polygon and measure polygon.

https://mib.helsinki.fi/help/main/ug_gui_menu_tools_measure.html

And I need to chew on

[Coco annotations: convert RLE to polygon segmentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75326066/coco-annotations-convert-rle-to-polygon-segmentation)

Comment: I don't think you're going to get much traction expecting anyone to watch a youtube video.  If there is relevant information in that you need to add it as text to your post.  Links are fine, but never as a primary source.  Please review the rules and guidelines on how to ask a question first as well as understand the purpose of this site:  It is *not* a discussion forum, it is a searchable knowledge base and links undermine that purpose.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask